# Unable to denormalize entity with the new Normalizr 3.1.0

Tags: javascript, normalizr

I'm trying to denormalize a user back into a complete object. I'm trying to follow based on the docs [here](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#denormalizeinput-schema-entities). From what I understand the input should be one of the result values, and then you provide the schema and entities to process rebuilding the object. The returned value though is an object that has a key of 0 and a value of the input. `{0:44}` for example, instead of the whole denormalized user object.

userSchemas.js

```
import { schema } from 'normalizr';

const photos = new schema.Entity('photos')
const phones = new schema.Entity('phones')
const user = new schema.Entity('users', {
    photos: [photos],
    phones: [phones]
})

const usersSchema = new schema.Array(users)

export { usersSchema, user as userSchema }
```

denormalizing

```
denormalize([user], userSchema, this.props.users.entities)
```

this.props.users.entities

```
{
users : { 
         1: {id:1, name: "john", phones:[2]}
        },
photos : {},
phones : {
          2: {id:2, phone: "34234324"}
         }
}
```

EDIT: Gist that can be pasted into http://requirebin.com that shows the issue in console

```
var normalizr = require("normalizr")

const photos = new normalizr.schema.Entity('photos')
const phones = new normalizr.schema.Entity('phones')
const user = new normalizr.schema.Entity('user', {
    photos: [photos],
    phones: [phones]
})

const usersSchema = new normalizr.schema.Array(user)

var users = [
  {id: 1, name: "bob", phones: [{id:3, phone: 45234324},{id:4, phone: 42342432}]},
    {id: 2, name: "will", phones: [{id:3, phone: 45234324},{id:6, phone: 5435345}]},
    {id: 4, name: "sam", phones: [{id:6, phone: 5345353},{id:7, phone: 42342432}]}
]

var normalizedUsers = normalizr.normalize(users, usersSchema)

var denormalizedUser = normalizr.denormalize([2], user, normalizedUsers)

console.log(denormalizedUser)
```

Comment: What is the value of `this.props.users.entities`? I suspect this may be where you problem is.

Comment: I've updated the OP with the this.props.users.entities data

Comment: Is the `user` that you're passing in `denormalize([user],...` the exported schema? Because that should be a normalized user, not a schema. Only the second argument is supposed to be a schema.

Comment: so maybe that was part of the problem. I thought you could just pass in the id/key of the entity as the `input` to denormalize, rather than the whole object. can the `input` be an individual object or does it always need to be an array? I just want to denormalize a single user entity.

Comment: The ID of the entity should work. My question was: what is `user` in `denormalize([user], ...`. Without that, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Sorry, the user variable is an user entity id value.

Comment: Can you post a working test case with some actual data? (at least a stub that can be re-run to achieve the same result). This is impossible to help without having a full repro case.

Comment: Yup I will put something together as soon as I can. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: I'm not sure why I couldn't get the direct link to work, but you can paste [this gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/CoinGame/55fa94b956193658472bb1311d6092b1/raw/e768139fa6b3270a5983411c2fa6153114dedce3/denormalize) into [requirebin.com](https://requirebin.com) to run and check the console.

Comment: I think I messed up the requirebin link. it's http://requirebin.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
var denormalizedUser = normalizr.denormalize([2], user, normalizedUsers)
```

Either your first argument should just be `2` or your second argument should be `[ user ]`.

[edit]

Also, `normalizedUsers` should be just the `entities`, not the full normalized result. Use `normalizedUsers.entities`

Comment: When I try your modifications in the requirebin example it results in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined` on this line from normalizr `var entity = (typeof entityOrId === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(entityOrId)) === 'object' ? entityOrId : entities[this.key][entityOrId];`. I had tried your recommendation in my own code previously with the same result. I'm not sure why it doesn't find that key in the entities list provided, it's clearly there when I console.log the entities.

Comment: Edited... you need to pass JUST the entities object, not the normalized result.

Comment: Oh man this is perfect. You are the champ. Thanks for sticking it out with me on this.