# Denormalize with normalizr

Tags: redux, denormalization, normalizr

I am trying to denormalize some data from the redux state, but I can't get it to work. I have tried putting together the denormalize function in all ways I can think. It is a guessing game and nothing have worked so far.

First I normalize the product data and put it into the state. 
The entities are being put in `state.data.products`, including the products.

```
state.data: {

    products: {
          products: {
                 9:   {
                     id: 9
                     attributes: [ 10, 45, 23 ],
                     things: [23, 55, 77]
                  },

                 11     //etc 

            } 
           attributes: {

                10: {
                   id: 10
                },

                45:    //etc
            },

            things: {   //etc

     }
   }
```

So there is one property "products" that includes all entities, and there is another "products" for the "products" entity.

The normalizing works without problem:

```
normalize(data, [productSchema]);
```

The "productSchema" is defined like this:

```
productSchema = new schema.Entity('products', {
    attributes: [attributeSchema],
    things: [thingsSchema],
    //+ other stuff
});
```

Now I want to denormalize a product, for example 9.

I use "connect" in a view component to call this function to retrieve the data from state and denormalize it:

```
export const denormalizeProduct = (state, productId) => {
      const entities = state.data.products;

    return denormalize( 
            productId, 
            [productSchema],
            entities
    );
}
```

If I call `denormalizeProductById(state, 9)` , I only get `9` back.
(similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828649/unable-to-denormalize-entity-with-the-new-normalizr-3-1-0) , but I couldn't find a solution from it, and it mixes together two examples)

If I put the "productSchema" without the array:

```
return denormalize( 
            productId, 
            productSchema,
            entities
    );
```

I get the error: `TypeError: entities[schemaKey] is undefined`.
Everything I have tried results in either "9" or the above error.

---

**Edit**:
found the error - added it below

Comment: It should be `productSchema` without brackets, since you're not denormalizing an array. Does the reselect stuff have anything to do with the problem? If not, it's clearer if you delete it here, and instead add all code for a minimal complete example (i.e. stripped down but complete definitions of `entities` and `productSchema` plus the failing `denormalize` call).

Comment: I removed the reselect function, but it's the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error - one of my schemas was wrong: I had created `new schema.Entity('shippingZones')` but in the reducer I added it to the state with a different name:

```
shipping_zones: action.payload.shippingZones
```

So it was looking for "shippingZones" while there was only "shipping_zones" I guess. So I changed it to  `new schema.Entity('shipping_zones')` and `shipping_zones: action.payload.shipping_zones`

It's a pity that the message `TypeError: entities[schemaKey] is undefined` couldn't have specified "shippingZones" , then I could have saved a few days time.

So this code worked in the end:

```
const entities = state.data.products; 

return denormalize( 
        productId, 
        productSchema,
        entities
);
```